# i am not getting distinct record using this query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 select distinct
 (mc."Member Id"),
mc."Member Last Name",
mc."Member Middle Name",
mc."Member First Name",

mc."Member DOB",
mc."Claim DOS",
mwc."Later Visit Date",
mc."Service Paid/Denied",
mc."Claim Number",
mc."Facility Name",
mc."Facility Id",
mc."Facility Address",
mc."Facility Phone Number",
mc."Facility Fax",

mc."Provider Name",
mc."Provider Id"
from member_cdt mc  inner join member_withoutcdt mwc ON mc."Member Id" = mwc."Member Id" 
where mc."Claim DOS" <>  mwc."Later Visit Date"
order by 1
```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: i am still getting duplicate member id

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `distinct on`, not `select distinct`:

```
select distinct on (mc."Member Id") mc."Member Id", . . .
from member_cdt mc inner join
     member_withoutcdt mwc
     on mc."Member Id" = mwc."Member Id" 
where mc."Claim DOS" <>  mwc."Later Visit Date"
order by mc."Member Id";
```

This syntax (which is specific to Postgres), returns one row for each set of key values in parentheses.  The contents of the row are the columns after the parentheses.

Notes:

- There is no comma after the closing paren for `distinct on`.
- `mc."Member Id"` is both in parentheses and in the column list afterwards.  The first reference is used for selecting unique rows; the second is for returning the value.
- Normally, there is an additional `order by` key to specify *which* of the duplicate records that you want.